# Would like to have Jquery Effect only on Main Menu and not Sub Menu

Tags: jquery, css

Glad to be out here on Stack Overflow :)

I recently implemented some Jquery fade in/fade out code for my WordPress menu. I actually used the code found [here](http://www.queness.com/post/411/create-an-attractive-jquery-menu-with-fadein-and-fadeout-effect/page/6#comments) at this resource. Apparently, it seems like a piece of Jquery code that's pretty commonly used.

I was able to get it incorporated into my WordPress menus. Everything works great on the primary navs. However, the sub menus adopt the same height and Jquery effect of the primary nav which I do not want. I'd like the sub menus to be thinner and just have a simple background color change.

My question is how I can get the styles of the primary and sub navs to be independent of each other while using this great jquery script. I've pasted the relevant css code and was hoping someone might be able to offer some insight. It's based off of the standard wordpress menu css and am hoping it's pretty self-explanatory.

```
#access {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    line-height:60px;
}
#access ul {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'swis721_ltcn_btlight';
    text-transform:uppercase;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 -0.8125em;
    padding-left: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
#access li {
    float:left; 
    background:url(images/default.jpg) no-repeat center center; /
    width:150px;    
    height: 50px;                       
    position:relative;          
}
#access li a {
    z-index:20;     
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    color:#777;
    border-right: 1px dotted #cccccc;
}

#access li .hover {
    background:url(images/over.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    position:absolute;  
    width:150px;    
    height:50px;
    left:0;
    top:0;  
    z-index:0;      
    display:none;       
}

#access ul ul {
    height: 17px !important;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    display: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    z-index: 99999;
}

#access ul ul a {
    background:#ccc;
    border-top: 1px dotted #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #ffffff;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.1em;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    width: 130px;
    height: 17px;
}

#access ul ul :hover > a {
    height:17px !important;
}
```

Basically, when I attempt to change the sub menus styles in "#access ul ul a" or"#access ul ul :hover > a" the heights and hover effects of the primary nav carry over.

I've included a link to an example of the issue. If you hover over 'events and services' you'll see the sub menu issue.

http://streetsmartetiquette.com/wordpress/about/

Jquery Code added below as well:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    //Append a div with hover class to all the LI
    $('#menu-navmenu li').append('<div class="hover"><\/div>');


    $('#menu-navmenu li').hover(

        //Mouseover, fadeIn the hidden hover class  
        function() {

            $(this).children('div').stop(true, true).fadeIn('1000');    

        }, 

        //Mouseout, fadeOut the hover class
        function() {

            $(this).children('div').stop(true, true).fadeOut('1000');   

    }).click (function () {

        //Add selected class if user clicked on it
        $(this).addClass('selected');

    });

});
```

Thanks all for the help!

Comment: Can you please add your jquery part, i think this is where the problem is

Comment: Hi @Dany Y, Thank you for the response. I've included my Jquery code below:jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 //Append a div with hover class to all the LI
 $('#menu-navmenu li').append('<div class="hover"><\/div>');


 $('#menu-navmenu li').hover(
  
  //Mouseover, fadeIn the hidden hover class 
  function() {
   
   $(this).children('div').stop(true, true).fadeIn('1000'); 
  
  }, 
 
  //Mouseout, fadeOut the hover class
  function() {
  
   $(this).children('div').stop(true, true).fadeOut('1000'); 
  
 }).click (function () {
 
  $(this).addClass('selected');
 });
});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i think your problem is in your css you're not separating the first ul li from you menus and the ul li from your submenus

Create new css with

```
#access .sub-menu li {  
    height: 18px; // the height you need for the submenu or anything else you ant to change                                
}
```

and

```
#access .sub-menu li .hover {
height: 18px;// the height you need for the hover effect from the jquery                                
}
```

Comment: Hey Dany, That makes perfect sense. I dropped those styles into the CSS but the sub menus are still 50px long and apply the Jquery effect.  I put a test border inside the "#access .submenu li" style and it didn't appear on the website. Do you think it's css thing or something that I would need to tinker with in the Jquery command? Thx again for the help

Comment: i think it's more of a css thing. are you familiar with the dev tools of chrome or firefox ? they show you each element what css they're using, and you can edit them live to see.is the new css on http://streetsmartetiquette.com/wordpress/about/ ?

Comment: Yes, i have firebug installed on my Chrome. I feel like with your help, I'm getting much closer. I just need to find a way to independently affect the sub menus in general now. The #access .submenu li reference makes sense but for some reason doesn't work. Any additional thoughts on that?

Comment: ah there is a typo its `#access .sub-menu li` and not `submenu`

Comment: Wow---great catch man. I completely missed that! It works great and your help is MUCH appreciated. The Jquery effect is no longer showing and the sub menu is the right height. However, there's still a gap between the two sub menus. Can you recommend the cleanest way of getting rid of this inbetween?

Comment: where's the gap ?between "ask Diane" and "test" ?

Comment: Yup that's the one. Is there also a way to disable the actual jQuery from running even behind the sub menu hover. I know it won't matter if you have a color-background but just out of principle, it'd be great to not have it even kick in. Thanks again for the assistance

Comment: if you want to prevent to make the effect on the submenu, replace `$('#menu-navmenu li')` with `$('#menu-navmenu>li')` it will work only on the direct `li` children, not the `li` of any level

Comment: One more thing, after playing around some more with it, I still am unable to add a test border to the "#access .sub-menu li class. Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thx

Comment: nevermind...I found out I had an extra typo in my code. We're good to go :) Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have a lot of time, but I threw this together quick:

HTML

```
<nav id="access">
    <div class="menu-navmenu-container">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Link 1</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="/">Link 2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/">Sub Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Sub Link 2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
#access {}
.menu-navmenu-container { width : 960px; }

#access ul {
    list-style : none;
}
#access li {
    float : left;
    position : relative;
    text-align : center;
    width : 150px;
}
#access li a {
    border-left : 1px solid #ccc;
    display : block;
    line-height : 50px;
}
#access li:last-child a { border-right : 1px solid #ccc; }
#access li a:hover {
    background-image : url("http://streetsmartetiquette.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/clean/images/over.jpg");
}

#access ul ul {
    border-top : 1px solid #ccc;
    left : 0;
    padding : 0;
    position : absolute;
}
#access ul ul a {
    border-bottom : 1px solid #ccc;
    line-height : normal;
    padding : 5px 0;
}
#access ul ul a:hover {
    background-color : blue;
    background-image : none;
    color : white;
}
```

And here's a [link to the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xwtEQ/). It's javascript free, but you can implement your javascript if need be.

Comment: Hey Kacey, Thanks for the reply and taking the time to put the code together. I pasted it into my stylesheet and I see that the primary and sub menus have different styles. However, the Jquery effect no longer appears on the primary menus. Do you know of some tweaks that can be made to ensure that the primary menus keep their cool jquery effects?

Comment: @user2325396 Have a look at this new fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/xwtEQ/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/xwtEQ/2/). It includes jQuery that adds the `hover` element, and transitions it accordingly.

Comment: Nice! I'll be checking that out. Thanks for the reference :)

Comment: Hey Kacey, Thanks again for the reference. The strange thing is that when I used the site's Jquery code along with the new css, it didn't work. But when I used the original Jquery code with the new CSS, it worked :) Any ideas what the differences were? You're help has bee MOST appreciated